# Instantiate model instance with manytomany field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I have a method that works, but it seems very clumsy, and I would think there is a better way to do this.

I have a Model that relates a user on my site (a twitter clone for learning purposes) to a list of other users.

Right now when I create a new user, I want to initialize that list with the user as a member of the list.

My model is:

```
class FollowerList(models.Model)
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="follower")
    followed = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="followed")
```

The code in my view that I'm using right now is

```
user = User.objects.get(username=uname)
flst = FollowerList()
flst.follower = user
flst.save()
flst.followed.add(user)
flst.save()
```

It seems to me like there *should* be a method for creating this without calling `save()` twice, but I can't seem to find it in the docs or anywhere else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to call save after the many2many.add()

You could also shorten the code to 2 lines:

```
flst = FollowerList.objects.create(follower=user)
flst.followed.add(user)
```

Comment: The issue when I do this is that I get an error saying the FollowerList object must have a primary key before it can add the ManyToManyField instances to it. And the only way I can see to get that is to instantiate it first and save it then add the other field.

Comment: Well, FollowerList.objects.create(follower=user) will give it a primary key. It does the save.

Comment: @jperelli, yes, sprinkled throughout the topics on ManyToMany (google it) and a detailed reference here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference

Answer (score 4):

Yuji's answer is correct. You can not add an object to a M2M field until it has been saved. I wanted to mention a shorter way to create instances though.

```
user = User.objects.get(username=uname)
flst = FollowerList(follower=user) #use key word args to assign fields
flst.save()
flst.followed.add(user)
# don't need to save after adding an object to many to many field.
```

I find that syntax slightly nicer than creating an empty instance and assigning fields. Though the objects.create() method (mentioned by Yuki) is nicer still.

Answer (score 2):

*A late answer to this*: you could also override the constructor (`__init__`) as follows:

```
class FollowerList(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="follower")
    followed = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="followed"

    def __init__(*args, followed=[], **kwargs):
        super(FollowerList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.save()
        for user in followed:
            self.followed.add(user)
```

ie here I've explicitly handled the `followed` keyword argument in the `__init__` function, while passing all other `args` and `kwargs` on to the default constructor. 
The call to `save` makes sure that the object has been registered and can thus be used in an m2m relationship.

This then allows you to do create `FollowerList` with one line, eg

```
flst = FollowerList(follower=user, followed=[user,])
```

Alternatively, as pointed out by Johannes, saving a model in the `__init__` is not expected. The preferred approach would be to create a `Manager` method - see here for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/
and then to create a `FollowerList`:

```
fl = FollowerList.objects.create(*args, followed, **kwargs)
```

Comment: not really sure if saving the model in the init method is a good idea though. i would not expect that to happen if i create an instance of a new object (if i want to have it saved to the database straight i'd rather call objects.create())